# Sort Files By Modification Time in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

So my current code:

```
$path = 'C:\\movies';
$d = dir($path);
$movies = array();
$movietimes = array();
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read()))
{
    if($entry !== '.' AND $entry !== '..')
    {
        $stat = stat($path.'\\'.$entry);
        $movietimes[] = $stat['ctime'];
        $movies[] = $entry;
    }
}
$d->close();
natsort($movietimes);
$movietimes = array_reverse($movietimes, true);
foreach($movietimes as $k=>$v)
{
    echo $movies[$k];
}
```

However now I want to be able to access three at a time.
Any ideas?

Comment: movies see the line: echo $movies[$k];

Comment: `array_chunk` the sorted array and loop over the chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have an array of keys you want to sort the other array according to, you can use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array_multisort) to do so:

```
array_multisort($movietimes, SORT_DESC, $movie);
```

With this the values in `$movietimes` are sorted in descending order and then used to order the corresponding values in `$movie`.